# JsonReaderException in AWS Lambda C# Function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, querystringparameter

I have created an aws lambda function using c# in visual studio 2017 and I'm having problems with the parameters. I am trying to get the 'querystringparameter'
but every time I put a parameter in my FunctionHandler I get this error.

```
{
  "errorType": "JsonReaderException",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
  ]
}
```

This is my sample FunctionHandler code :

```
public string FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var sample = GetParameters(request.QueryStringParameters, "sample");
            return sample;
        }
```

What's wrong with this ? Answers would be very much appreciated. Thank you !

**UPDATE**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmGLB.png)

Comment: What is the input do you pass to the lambda?

Comment: I pass a query parameter via API Gateway.

Comment: can you please provide how you are passing the parameters, I mean the format of JSON values

Comment: I pass the parameter via API Gateway when I'm testing it. I've also tried just passing in a string via testing of function in visual studio 2017 but I still get that same error.

Comment: the parameter you are passing is not a valid JSON format.

Comment: Please see the image in my update as to how I pass the parameter to the function in testing. Thank you.

Comment: can you please try "{ \"param\": \"value\" }", check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The exception means you are not passing your parameter as a valid `JSON` format. please make sure to pass your parameter in a string quoted format.

```
public string myFunctionHandler(string param, ILambdaContext context){
....
}
```

Passing parameter (in a string quoted format) should be looking like:

```
"{ \"param\": \"value\" }"
```

If you have an object:

```
public string myFunctionHandler(JObject param, ILambdaContext context) {
...
}
```

In this case, you can pass it like this:

```
{ "param": "value" }
```

Comment: How about if I want to pass it as a query parameter but not via AWS API Gateway ? Like, http://api.com/v1?param=sample ...

Comment: @anonymous Such query parameter mapping can be configured as mentioned http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html